# regex to find words that differ by one letter

Tags: regex

I have a long alphabetical list of words separated by `\n` and a set of pairs of characters such as 'c' and 'f'. I would like to find words that differ by just these two letters, such as "can" and "fan", "came" and "fame" and "rice" and "rife".

This regex finds me some pair of words, in a short list, as you can [see here](https://regex101.com/r/xX8nG4/2):

```
/\n(.*?)c(.*?)\n(.*?\n)*?\1f\2\n/g
```

However, it does not show me any matches that overlap with the matches it finds first, and it runs out of stack space when I use it on my long list.

How can I improve this so that I can find all the matches in my word list?

Comment: I'm certainly not the world's foremost expert on regex, but this strikes me as something that is not a problem to be solved with regex.

Comment: You may want to indicate what regex flavor you need for your answer.

Comment: I'm working in Sublime Text at the moment, but I could use a different flavour if that were necessary.

Comment: > *I would like to find words that differ by just these two letters,*  Underspecified. From the examples it seems that the requirement is to find pairs of words which **are of equal length**, which differ by exactly one letter **in the same position**.  So for instance "cat" and "tact" are not viable pairs at all, and "cat" and "act" differ in two places, so do not constitute a pair which must be found. The pair "cat" and "bat" must be found (if both words occur in the dictionary).

Comment: Furthermore, the letters in which they differ must correspond to a given input pair of letters such as C or F. If C and B are the input letters, then "cat" and "bat" are reported, but not "cat" and "fat", which *are* reported if the letters are C and F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With multiple lookaheads it is possible. Have a look at this regex:

```
(\b(\w*?)([cf])(\w*)\b)(?=[\s\S]*(\b\2(?!\3)[cf]\4\b))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xX8nG4/3)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(         # start group #1
  \b      # word boundary
  (\w*?)  # group #2, capture 0 or more word chars
  ([cf])  # group #3, capture letters c OR f
  (\w*)   # group #4, capture remaining word chars on RHS of c or f
  \b      # word boundary
)         # end group #1
(?=       # start of lookahead
  [\s\S]* # match 0 or more of any char including newline
  (       # start group #5
     \b   # word boundary
     \2   # back-reference to group #2
     (?!\3)[cf] # c or f but make sure it is reverse of earlier match using back-reference
     \4   # back-reference to group #4
     \b   # word boundary
  )       # end of group #5
)         # end of lookahead
```

**Your result is available in captured group #1 and captured group #5.**

Comment: This gives me some false positives, possibly due to duplicates in my word list, but it does a good job for what I need.

Comment: Actually I had missed one word boundary at the end of lookahead. Fixed it now.